# Accompanist systemUiController darkIcons doesn't work on Android 11

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-statusbar, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I'm using the Accompanist systemUiController library and I'm setting
`darkIcons=false`

while in Light Theme but the effect doesn't apply on devices with android 11. It seems to work on devices with android 10 for example.

This is the code with which I'm trying to set the colors.

```
 val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
 systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(color=statusBarColor,darkIcons=false)
```

where `statusBarColor` is a darker color which represents the reason I want white foreground/icons

While in Dark Theme it works to set  `darkIcons`
to both `true` and `false` and the effect applies accordingly

This is the status bar on LightTheme with `darkIcons=false` and `darkIcons=true`
[image]

This is the status bar on DarkTheme with `darkIcons=false`
[image]

This is the status bar on DarkTheme with `darkIcons=true`
[image]

For reference this is my whole `Theme.kt`

```
private val LightBase = ASBTheme(
    material = lightColors(
        background = FigmaPrimaryWhite,
        onBackground = FigmaTextBlack,
        surface = FigmaPrimaryWhite,
        onSurface = FigmaTextBlack,
        primary = FigmaSecondaryAvastBlue,
        error = FigmaStatusPink,
    ),
    textColorLabel = FigmaSecondaryAvastPurple,
    colorAccent = FigmaPrimaryGreen,
    ... //bunch of custom colors
)

private val DarkBase = ASBTheme(
    material = darkColors(
        background = FigmaPrimaryBlackBg,
        onBackground = FigmaTextWhite,
        surface = FigmaSecondaryAvastBlueDark,
        onSurface = FigmaTextWhite,
        primary = FigmaSecondaryBlackDark,
        error = FigmaStatusPink
    ),
        textColorLabel = FigmaSecondaryAvastPurpleBright,
        colorAccent = FigmaStatusGreen,
        ... //bunch of custom colors
)

private val LocalAsbTheme = staticCompositionLocalOf { LightBase }
var navBarColor: Color? = null
var statusBarColor: Color? = null

@Composable
fun ASBTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkBase
    } else {
        LightBase
    }
    if (darkTheme) {
        navBarColor = DarkBase.background
        statusBarColor = DarkBase.primary
    } else {
        navBarColor = LightBase.background
        statusBarColor = LightBase.primary
    }

    SetBarsTheme(statusBarColor!!, navBarColor!!)

    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalAsbTheme provides colors,
    ) {
        MaterialTheme(
            colors = colors.material,
            content = content,
        )
    }
}

val MaterialTheme.asbTheme: ASBTheme
    @Composable
    @ReadOnlyComposable
    get() = LocalAsbTheme.current
```

`SetBarsTheme()` is where I'm trying to set the status bar colors depending on the lifecycle event so that the colors would maintain after `onPause() / onStop()`. I also tried to set the colors outside of this logic and the bug still persists.

```
@Composable
fun SetBarsTheme(
    statusBarColor: Color,
    navigationBarColor: Color,
    darkIcons:Boolean=false,
) {
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()

    DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
        // Create an observer that triggers our remembered callbacks
        // for sending analytics events
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME) {
               systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(color=statusBarColor,darkIcons)
                systemUiController.setNavigationBarColor(color=navigationBarColor)
            }
        }

        // Add the observer to the lifecycle
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)

        // When the effect leaves the Composition, remove the observer
        onDispose {
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: @tim, there's a [fixed bug](https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues/949), make sure you're using the latest Accompanist version. If you still able to reproduce it, you should [report it](https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues/new?assignees=alexvanyo&labels=&template=system-ui-controller-bug-report.md&title=%5BSystem+UI+Controller%5D+), including used device/dependencies versions.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov probably right. I haven't been able to test it due to compileSdk not being 31 yet. Post the answer if you want the bounty

Answer (score 2):

There's a [fixed bug](https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues/949), make sure you're using the latest Accompanist version.

If you still able to reproduce it, you should [report it](https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues/new?assignees=alexvanyo&labels=&template=system-ui-controller-bug-report.md&title=%5BSystem%20UI%20Controller%5D%20), including used device/dependencies versions.

Comment: It does indeed fix the issue, however I had my own dependency on androidx.core and I had to bump that to 1.8.0-alpha04 as well for it to work.